# How to fetch specific elements from an array and create a new array based on the comparison of an array key's value?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value

My question may sound confusing to some people. But in fact it's a quite simple one. Let me clear you the scenario. I've an array titled `$test_result_data` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 8ed32f6479a0169db3531d3366996d35
            [test_pack_name] => CPT Free Samples
            [test_pack_desc] => This package contains a free sample test of 30 minutes containing 30 questions from - Fundamentals of accounting, Mercantile Law, General Economics and Quantitative Aptitude. This is perfect to discover the beauty of online exam preparation.
            [test_pack_type_id] => 7
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 3
            [test_pack_plan] => free
            [test_pack_price] => 0.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_code] => 
            [test_pack_sold] => 22
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1337014879
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1376886700
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 1364454118
            [test_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 159
                            [test_name] => CPT Sample Test
                            [test_max_score] => 120.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 30
                            [test_attempt] => 15
                            [test_not_attempt] => 7
                            [avg_test_user_time_used] => 00:04:39 Hr
                            [top_score] => 46.00
                            [avg_score] => 3
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b
            [test_pack_name] => CPT General Economics
            [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains <b>16 chapterwise testlets</b> of 15 minutes each, <b>8 chapterwise tests </b>of 1 hour each and <b>3 full syllabus tests</b> of 1 hour covering syllabus of CPT General Economics.<br>
<b>Total Tests in this Package : 27</b>
            [test_pack_type_id] => 7
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 6
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => paid
            [test_pack_price] => 359.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_code] => 
            [test_pack_sold] => 0
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1338298119
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1343564534
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 0
            [test_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 580
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 581
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Micro Economics
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 583
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 582
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 579
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 578
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Demand & Supply
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 577
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Production & Cost 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 576
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Production & Cost 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 575
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Production & Cost
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 574
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Price Determination 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 573
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Price Determination 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 572
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Price Determination
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 571
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Indian Economy - A Profile 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 570
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Indian Economy - A Profile 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 569
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Indian Economy - A Profile
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 568
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Aspects of Indian Economy 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 567
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Aspects of Indian Economy 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 566
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Aspects of Indian Economy
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 565
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Economic Reforms in India 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 564
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Economic Reforms in India 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 563
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Economic Reforms in India
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 562
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Money & Banking 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 561
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Money & Banking 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 560
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Money & Banking
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 559
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : General Economics 1
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 558
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : General Economics 2
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 557
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : General Economics 3
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now you can see that this array has two main arrays inside it. Each of these arrays contain Test Package Data. This array creates dynamically so we can't say how many items each time it will contain. Now I'm haing one `$test_pack_id` and I want to fetch only those array elements from the above array where the value of a key [test_pack_id] mathes with the value of a variable `$test_pack_id`. I want to create a whole new array for these matching test package data items. Can anyone please help me in getting this array?

Suppose I have following variable:

```
$test_pack_id = '84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b';//This is my input
```

The array `$test_result_data` can contain this id in it's elements one time, more than one time or it doesn't contain. But if match found then it should return all the matching elements. In above case the output shoud be as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
[test_pack_id] => 84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b
                [test_pack_name] => CPT General Economics
                [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains <b>16 chapterwise testlets</b> of 15 minutes each, <b>8 chapterwise tests </b>of 1 hour each and <b>3 full syllabus tests</b> of 1 hour covering syllabus of CPT General Economics.<br>
    <b>Total Tests in this Package : 27</b>
                [test_pack_type_id] => 7
                [test_pack_image] => 
                [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
                [test_pack_validity_month] => 6
                [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
                [test_pack_plan] => paid
                [test_pack_price] => 359.00
                [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
                [test_pack_publish] => yes
                [test_pack_code] => 
                [test_pack_sold] => 0
                [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
                [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
                [test_pack_created_date] => 1338298119
                [test_pack_updated_date] => 1343564534
                [test_pack_purchase_date] => 0
                [test_details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [test_id] => 580
                                [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 1
                                [test_max_score] => 40.000
                                [test_no_questions] => 10
                                [test_attempt] => 0
                                [test_not_attempt] => 0
                                [top_score] => 
                                [avg_score] => 0
                                [lower_score] => 
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [test_id] => 581
                                [test_name] => CPT Test : Micro Economics
                                [test_max_score] => 50.000
                                [test_no_questions] => 50
                                [test_attempt] => 0
                                [test_not_attempt] => 0
                                [top_score] => 
                                [avg_score] => 0
                                [lower_score] => 
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [test_id] => 583
                                [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 1
                                [test_max_score] => 40.000
                                [test_no_questions] => 10
                                [test_attempt] => 0
                                [test_not_attempt] => 0
                                [top_score] => 
                                [avg_score] => 0
                                [lower_score] => 
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [test_id] => 582
                                [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 2
                                [test_max_score] => 40.000
                                [test_no_questions] => 10
                                [test_attempt] => 0
                                [test_not_attempt] => 0
                                [top_score] => 0.00
                                [avg_score] => 0
                                [lower_score] => 0.00
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [test_id] => 579
                                [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 2
                                [test_max_score] => 40.000
                                [test_no_questions] => 10
                                [test_attempt] => 0
                                [test_not_attempt] => 0
                                [top_score] => 
                                [avg_score] => 0
                                [lower_score] => 
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [test_id] => 578
                                [test_name] => CPT Test : Demand & Supply
                                [test_max_score] => 50.000
                                [test_no_questions] => 50
                                [test_attempt] => 0
                                [test_not_attempt] => 0
                                [top_score] => 0.00
                                [avg_score] => 0
                                [lower_score] => 0.00
                            )




                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter):

```
$filtered = array_filter($yourArray, function($element) use($test_pack_id) {
  return $element['test_pack_id'] == $test_pack_id;
});
```

Comment: But it's starting index from 1. I want it to start the index from 0. Can you please modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: @PHPLover try adding $filtered = array_values($filtered);

Comment: but where? Can you please modify your answer to get this change?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
function packed_element($id) {
foreach($test_result_data as $k => $v)
  if ($v->test_pack_id === $id)
    return $v;
}
```

But if you can manage the code that generate the array I suggest you to simply use dictionary array over simple one, that have your id as key. So you can referrer to your element directly. For example you can generate an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [8ed32f6479a0169db3531d3366996d35] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 8ed32f6479a0169db3531d3366996d35
            [test_pack_name] => CPT Free Samples
            [test_pack_desc] => This package contains a free sample test of 30 minutes containing 30 questions from - Fundamentals of accounting, Mercantile Law, General Economics and Quantitative Aptitude. This is perfect to discover the beauty of online exam preparation.
            [test_pack_type_id] => 7
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 3
            [test_pack_plan] => free
            [test_pack_price] => 0.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_code] => 
            [test_pack_sold] => 22
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1337014879
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1376886700
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 1364454118
            [test_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 159
                            [test_name] => CPT Sample Test
                            [test_max_score] => 120.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 30
                            [test_attempt] => 15
                            [test_not_attempt] => 7
                            [avg_test_user_time_used] => 00:04:39 Hr
                            [top_score] => 46.00
                            [avg_score] => 3
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b] => Array
        (
            [test_pack_id] => 84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b
            [test_pack_name] => CPT General Economics
            [test_pack_desc] => This Package contains <b>16 chapterwise testlets</b> of 15 minutes each, <b>8 chapterwise tests </b>of 1 hour each and <b>3 full syllabus tests</b> of 1 hour covering syllabus of CPT General Economics.<br>
<b>Total Tests in this Package : 27</b>
            [test_pack_type_id] => 7
            [test_pack_image] => 
            [test_pack_validity_year] => 0
            [test_pack_validity_month] => 6
            [test_pack_validity_days] => 0
            [test_pack_plan] => paid
            [test_pack_price] => 359.00
            [test_pack_no_tests] => 0
            [test_pack_publish] => yes
            [test_pack_code] => 
            [test_pack_sold] => 0
            [test_pack_created_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [test_pack_created_date] => 1338298119
            [test_pack_updated_date] => 1343564534
            [test_pack_purchase_date] => 0
            [test_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 580
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 581
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Micro Economics
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 583
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 582
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Micro Economics 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 579
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Demand & Supply 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 578
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Demand & Supply
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 577
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Production & Cost 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 576
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Production & Cost 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 575
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Production & Cost
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 574
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Price Determination 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 573
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Price Determination 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 572
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Price Determination
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 571
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Indian Economy - A Profile 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 570
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Indian Economy - A Profile 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 569
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Indian Economy - A Profile
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 568
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Aspects of Indian Economy 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 567
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Aspects of Indian Economy 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 566
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Aspects of Indian Economy
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 565
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Economic Reforms in India 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 564
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Economic Reforms in India 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 563
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Economic Reforms in India
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 562
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Money & Banking 1
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 561
                            [test_name] => CPT Testlet : Money & Banking 2
                            [test_max_score] => 40.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 10
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 560
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : Money & Banking
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 559
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : General Economics 1
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 558
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : General Economics 2
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 0.00
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 0.00
                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [test_id] => 557
                            [test_name] => CPT Test : General Economics 3
                            [test_max_score] => 50.000
                            [test_no_questions] => 50
                            [test_attempt] => 0
                            [test_not_attempt] => 0
                            [top_score] => 
                            [avg_score] => 0
                            [lower_score] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And then you can to simply this:

$my_packed_data = $test_result_data[84880f321fc957f9b28b702d5a43f57b];

Comment: You cannot use this array as an object.

Comment: why you can't use this as object? if I do this: $object = (object) $my_packed_data; I think it's work!